# How to use html GET request with bootstrap to get input values?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-views, bootstrap-4

I wrote an HTML code with the bootstrap library.  Mainly, i want someone to go to this website, type in their info, and I store their inputs to do some internal analysis. After user enters his input, the url gets redirected to a 'search' url.   My code is as follows:

html

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h2 style="color:blue;"> Welcome to my website </h2>
    </div></div>


<script>
function formSubmit() {document.forms["cust_info"].submit();
}
</script>
<body>

  <form name="cust_info" action ="/search/" method="get" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
             <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="fname">First Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fname">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="mname">Middle Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="mname">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lname">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="address">Address:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="address">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="city">City:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="city">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="state">State:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="state">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="zip">Zip:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="zip">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    <input type = "button" onclick="formSubmit()"  value="Submit">
            </div></div>
  </form>
</body>
```

{% endblock content %}

The error im getting is:

```
Multivaludictkeyerror at search.  Basically, i have another file called views.py where i have written a function: 

def do_something(request):
    first_name = request.GET['fname']
```

Hence I am gettin an error: except value: 'fname'.

Can anybody help?  How do i use a GET request to store the variable names?  Thanks

Screen shot of actual error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post the actual error?

Comment: hey @Skam, I attached the actual errors.  Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with bootstrap.

Comment: it probably doesn't.  But isn't horizontal forms part of the bootstrap library?  got it from https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the correct answer is we need to include a name attribute:

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fname",name='fname'>
```

and then it works!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your view and specifically the line

```
first_name = request.GET['fname']
```

This won't work since when you first open the page the request.GET dictionary will be empty and there won't be an `fname` key. The `[]` operator throws an error when the key is nto found. Thus the most easy solution would be to use `get` instead and check if there's a value. Something like this:

```
first_name = request.GET.get('fname')
if first_name:
    #first_name has been filled...
```